# Controlling output of time left

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to add some php which show the time left for a prodcut on my site, a little bit like an auction. It all displays well however when the time gets lower it shows `0d 34h 12m` which means 0 days, 34 hours and 12 minutes, i was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the 0d bit if there are no days left a bit like this `34h 12m`, it just makes it look better, the same for when there is no hours left and just minutes.

Here is the code that calculates the time left

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());
$date3 = new DateTime($date);
$date4 = new DateTime($time_ending);
$interval_date = $date3->diff($date4);
$time_left = $interval_date->d."d ". $interval_date->h."h ". $interval_date->i."m ";
```

Is there anyway i can do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the shortest way would be

```
$time_left = (($interval_date->d) ? $interval_date->d.'d ' : '')
           . (($interval_date->h) ? $interval_date->h.'h ' : '')
           . $interval_date->i.'m ';
```

Briefly explained `(cond) ? (stmA) : (stmB)`
equals `if(cond){ stmA } else{ stmB }`

Comment: ok great this works, and the day does not appear, however all the items i am testing still have hours left, when it gets to say 40 minutes, will it also stop the hours from displaying aswell? Thanks for your help

Comment: Cool :) You could do the same for the hours too, see edited code above ;)

Comment: ok great, i think that would work now, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function for that, see:

```
function BetterLook($time, $sulfix)
{
    if ($time > 0)
    {
        return "$time $sulfix";
    }

    return "";
}
```

So...

```
$time_left = BetterLook($interval_date->d, "d "). BetterLook($interval_date->h, "h "). BetterLook($interval_date->i, "m ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just written down, not tested.

```
$d = $interval_date->d;
$h = $interval_date->h;
$m = $interval_date->i; 

$time_left = ($d ? $d."d " : "") . ($d or $h ? $h."h " : "") . $i."m ";
```

Longer, maybe easier to read version:

```
$time_left = "";

if($d) {
    $time_left .= $d . "d ";
}

if($d or $h) {
    $time_left .= $h . "h ";
}

$time_left .= $m . "m ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple `if` statement to see if the `$interval_date->d` is less than 1?  If so then just show the remaining time.  You can do this each segment.  This is not tested, just a suggestion.